# PostgreSQL filter by many fields but Group by single field

Tags: postgresql

I have the table below and subsequent query.

**TABLE: sales**

[image]

This will work successfully (**group by all filter field**)

```
SELECT
    brand,
    SUM (total)
FROM
    sales
GROUP BY
    brand;
```

How about in even where i want to filter by both `brand and segment` and yet Group by `brand` alone ? Like below

```
SELECT
        brand,
        segment,
        SUM (total)
    FROM
        sales
    GROUP BY
        brand;
```

Comment: change the group by to be like this
GROUP BY
        brand,
        segment;

when using aggregate function you need to mention all other column in the group by clause

Comment: @justsomeone, thats what i am trying to avoid, is there to way

Comment: i do not think so but why you want to avoid that could you explain what exactly you want to achive

Comment: if same brand has multiple segment then what you wanna to show?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a group of rows like the following:

| brand | segment | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | parent | 100 |
| aaa | student | 50 |

And you run the query you suggest:

```
SELECT
    brand,
    segment,
    SUM (total)
FROM
    sales
GROUP BY
    brand;
```

By grouping, it returns exactly one row for the group defined by `brand` = 'aaa'.

What should it return for the `segment` column? It can only return one value, either 'parent' or 'student'. Which one? How can SQL know which one you want?

The *single-value rule* in SQL is that when you run a query with GROUP BY, all columns of the select-list must be either in aggregate functions, or else in the GROUP BY. Otherwise the column is ambiguous, because SQL cannot guess which value from the group you want.

So this query is okay, because it uses the aggregate function MAX() to pick one value from the `segment` column:

```
SELECT
    brand,
    MAX(segment),
    SUM (total)
FROM
    sales
GROUP BY
    brand;
```

Or this query is okay because it outputs multiple rows, one for each distinct pair of `brand` & `segment`.

```
SELECT
    brand,
    segment,
    SUM (total)
FROM
    sales
GROUP BY
    brand, segment;
```

Or this query is okay because it concatenates all the non-null values in `segment` into a comma-separated string. The comma-separated string is therefore a single string value, and that is okay by the single-value rule.

```
SELECT
    brand,
    STRING_AGG(segment, ','),
    SUM (total)
FROM
    sales
GROUP BY
    brand;
```

(`STRING_AGG()` is a PostgreSQL function. Other brands of database have similar functions but by another name. MySQL and SQLite for example use `GROUP_CONCAT()`.)